# Classe ou Enum?

Tags: orientação-a-objetos, engenharia-de-software, enums, projeto-de-software

Estou projetando um jogo de RPG em C# e encontrei um problema de decisão de projeto e preciso de ajuda para encontrar a maneira mais flexível para implementar o desejado.

Vou explicar um pouco do projeto:

- Existem algumas **raças** como `Elfo`, `Orc`, `Anão`, `Vampiro`, `Lobisomem`, etc.
- Existem **classes** como `Mago`, `Guerreiro`, `Ladino`, `Clérigo`, etc.
- Existem **atributos** como `Força`, `Destreza`, `Saúde`, `Energia`, `Inteligência`, etc.
- Cada personagem tem uma **raça** e uma **classe**.
- Existem **efeitos de status** como `Defesa Contra Fogo`, `Magia`, `Veneno`, `Índice de Armadura`, etc.
- Todos os personagens possuem os mesmos atributos (com valores diferentes, claro).
- O personagem poderá mudar de classe ao longo do jogo (mas não de raça).
- **Cada classe tem uma dádiva específica**.

A minha dúvida é: o que é classe e o que é enumeração?

Comment: Você realmente quis dizer `Ladino`? Ou seria `Paladino`? Além disso, acho que `Índice de Armadura` é um atributo, e não um efeito de status.

Comment: @VictorStafusa Sim, eu quis dizer `Ladino`. `Índice de Armadura pode ser um efeito de status` como, por exemplo, quando você toma uma poção ou usa uma magia para aumentar a sua armadura temporariamente. Veja a descrição de um ladino aqui http://rpgromaduke.weebly.com/classes-e-raccedilas.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Onde é bom usar enum?

A ideia de usar um enum se aplica nos seguintes casos:

- Trata-se de um conjunto fixo de elementos. Nenhum pode ser criado ou destruído.
- Os elementos são imutáveis. Ou seja, o conteúdo deles nunca muda, os valores internos de cada elemento são fixos.
- Correspondem a diversos valores distintos com comportamentos semelhantes entre si, apenas representando valores diferentes dentro de um grupo. Não convém usar polimorfismo.

Esses são bons exemplos de enums:

- Naipe de baralhos em um jogo de poker: ouro, copas, paus e espadas.
- Dias da semana: domingo, segunda-feira, terça-feira, ..., sábado.
- Meses do ano: janeiro, fevereiro, março, abril, ..., dezembro.
- Tipos de triângulos: equilátero, isósceles ou escaleno.
- Sexo de uma pessoa: feminino ou masculino.

São bons exemplos porque ninguém pode criar ou destruir um mês, um dia da semana ou um naipe de baralho em um jogo de poker (se pudesse, já não seria mais poker). Além disso, todos esses elementos têm o mesmo comportamento, e a menos que você esteja fazendo uma aplicação com regras muito peculiares ou gambiarradas, não faz sentido falar-se em polimorfismo ou comportamentos específicos nesses casos, pois março não tem métodos específicos que não aparecem no mês de junho e nem métodos que aparecem em ambos, mas com implementações completamente diferentes.

## Onde é bom usar diversas classes relacionadas?

Já esses daqui não são bons exemplos de enum e são melhores modelados como classes:

- Animal: gato, cachorro, papagaio, macaco, pato...
- Formas geométricas: quadrado, triângulo, losango, elipse...

O motivo é que esses daí são polimórficos. Pois cada figura tem uma forma diferente de calcular a área e o perímetro, além de possuirem atributos internos diferentes tais como raio, comprimento do lado, valores dos ângulos, etc. Também podem ter métodos diferentes específicos, pois a elipse vai ter o método `getSemieixoMaior()` que não tem e não faz sentido ter no triângulo.

Cada animal tem um comportamento diferente, uns andam, outros correm, outros voam, outros nadam, outros cantam (métodos específicos) e mesmo dois animais diferentes que cantam, cantam de formas bem diferentes (polimorfismo). Além disso sempre vai surgir um novo tipo de animal para incluir (ou seja, não é uma lista fixa).

## Onde é melhor usar-se uma só classe com valores de campos/atributos diferentes?

Esses daqui são melhores modelados com uma única classe que não é um enum:

- Estilos musicais: rock, samba, axé, reggae, jazz, gospel...
- Lista de cidades.
- Lista de depósitos de armazenagem.

O motivo é que cada objeto é uma nova instância, mas não há polimorfismo envolvido. De vez em quando inventam um novo gênero musical, e portanto seria melhor cadastrar a todos em um banco de dados, um arquivo texto ou csv, ou até mesmo apenas instanciá-los em algum ponto da execução e colocá-los em uma lista (não é uma lista fixa). O mesmo vale para a lista de cidades, pois cidades mudam de nome, podem ser desmembradas por emancipação de bairros ou fundidas por reformas geopolíticas, novas cidades podem ser fundadas.

Quanto a lista de depósitos de armazenagem, este daqui inclui porque é um caso real que já vi há 8 anos atrás. A empresa tinha depósitos em quatro cidades diferentes e o POGramador que fez o sistema originalmente teve a brilhante ideia de colocá-los em um enum. Adivinhe o que ocorreu quando foram abrir um novo depósito?

## Onde é melhor definir-se atributos/campos diferentes em uma mesma classe?

Esses daqui são simplesmente diversos atributos de uma mesma classe:

- Características que um indivíduo pode ter - peso, idade, altura...
- Valores descritivos de uma ordem de pagamento - nome do beneficiado, valor do pagamento, data do pagamento...

Em cada um desses casos, todos os elementos contém um valor dentro de cada instância de um determinado tipo de objeto. O objetivo dos valores denotados por esses elementos é descrever e caracterizar a instância no qual estão presentes.

## Os 4 casos que temos

Bem, com base nisso, então temos quatro casos:

- Enum - Use quando os valores são fixos e imutáveis e não possuem polimorfismo.
- Uma classe normal com várias instâncias diferentes - Use quando não há polimorfismo, mas os valores são mutáveis ou novas instâncias podem ser criadas ou instâncias já existentes destruídas.
- Múltiplas classes com uma superclasse ou interface em comum - Use quando há polimorfismo.
- Diferentes getters/propriedades de instância em uma classe - Use quando trata-se de características distintas de uma mesma coisa, cada uma com um valor diferente. Você armazena os valores básicos em atributos/campos e os disponibiliza por meio de getters/propriedades. Nos casos em que você tenha atributos cujos valores dependem de outros atributos (ex: diâmetro e raio), o getter pode ter que calcular o valor ao invés de apenas retorná-lo diretamente do campo/atributo.

## O seu caso

E agora vamos ver o seu caso em específico:

- Raça: Você pode querer inventar novas raças no futuro e há polimorfismo envolvido, logo use superclasse ou interface e cada raça tem a sua classe específica. Se não houver polimorfismo e for apenas o caso de valores diferentes para os campos/atributos, use uma mesma classe, crie as instâncias necessárias e adicione-as a uma lista ou um Map. Recomendo o uso do padrão de projeto *strategy*.
- Classe de personagem: Você pode querer inventar novas classes no futuro e há polimorfismo envolvido (pelo menos para modelar a dádiva), logo use superclasse ou interface e cada classe de personagem tem a sua classe C# específica. Se não houver polimorfismo e for apenas o caso de valores diferentes para os campos/atributos, use uma mesma classe do C#, crie as instâncias necessárias e adicione-as a uma lista ou um Map. O fato de um personagem poder mudar de classe sugere o uso do padrão de projeto *state*.
- Atributos: Acho que isso são os atributos/campos/getters/propriedades do seu personagem. Trata-se do conjunto de distintos valores que descrevem os seus personagens.
- Efeitos de status: Você pode querer inventar novos a qualquer hora. Além disso, é bem provável que você tenha polimorfismo, logo use superclasse ou interface e cada efeito tem a sua classe específica.